# Make a flying object rotate so the camera sees the rotation

Tags: unity, c#

When I attach a camera to my flying object (plane), when I rotate the object, the camera is perfectly following it so you can't really "feel" the plane rotating. I want to create the effect that you see in flying games where you see the plane rotating along the x axis (so you see the nose go up and tail down) while also semi-following the plane, creating a better effect.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can Lerp the math of the camera as it goes, which will smoothly follow the turn of the plane from behind.  You will not want the camera to be a child of the plane itself, or vice versa, for this to work, though it may be ideal to have the plane AND camera be a child of an empty object alongside one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good idea would be to link the camera to a GameObject inside your plane, like its gravity center, so you can control the camera rotation easily and it'll be independant from your acual plane.

This way, you can make your camera follow the plane on rotation if you want to, and you can also move your camera without moving the object.

#### Example:

I found those examples which are pretty much everything you need : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simplle-free-fly-camera-script.167604/
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-camera

Comment: Hate to ask, but I'm kinda new at Unity, how exactly would I do this? (I assume it's just a few steps).

Comment: @Paze I added some examples found on Unity forums :).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the effect can be achieved by simply not parenting the camera and using a script to do the same with addition of smoothness, that way the camera will be abit behind the rotation and then catch up, not instantly, and the rotation will seem more apparent.

Answer (score -1):

this should work. 1. Make a cube object. 2. Add a rgidBody to it. 3. Drrag the camera under it(child it). 4. On the cube, click the freeze restrain's arrow. This reveals 6 toggles. 5. Click the z of the bottom row, OR, the way your plane is rotating(by the x,y, or z axis). 6. Drag the cube that contains the camera under the plane object. 7. Now hit play and the cube won't rotate, and neither will the camera, and you can see the plane rotate.

Comment: This doesn't resolve what the OP asked for - which is the partial follow; something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B17om88MjZ4